# Arff to SVM Light

Tags: machine-learning, weka, svm, arff, svmlight

I have created a weka arff, which I'd like to convert to SVMLight format. This is so I can load the arff in [MLComp](http://mlcomp.org/). How do I go about converting an arff?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is you upload your data to http://mldata.org . Alternatively use the tool behind to do the conversion that you can get at

https://github.com/open-machine-learning/mldata-utils

With that you can convert from arff to svm light and between various other formats.

Comment: Thanks. The site is really fragile, and doesn't seem to be working well. In the github repo you linked to, which bit of code would help with conversion?